# How did I get the result of '6.03' and '23.24'? - Java Parameter Return

Tags: java

I wonder how did I get the result of '6.03' and '23.24'? System.out.println(a+b+c) does not add up to those 2 numbers?

Why is there a return c + "" + a? There is no output result show c + a?

The full code as follows:

MyProgram:

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public void start() 
    {
        String result;
        result = lots(2+1, 3, "3");
        result = lots(22, 1.2, "4");        
    }
    private String lots(int a, double b, String c) 
    {
        System.out.println(a+b+c);
        return c + "" + a;
    }
}
```

MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MyProgram p = new MyProgram();
        p.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: What exact output do you expect?

Comment: Judging by the 2 questions you have asked on this site, I suggest you start with Java's [Language Basics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) and the other associated tutorials on that website.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense because you're concatenating some string at the end of all of that math.

For the first run, you pass in 3 and 3.0 as your first two numerical parameters.  That adds to 6.0 (it's been since upcast to `double`).  You now then do string concatenation on `3` to arrive at `6.03` for your answer.

Trace through the second execution of the method to arrive at a similar answer.  Remember:  `+` is **overloaded** in Java to mean **either** numeric addition **or** string concatenation.

You overwrite `result` after you get it the first time, but even then, you don't do anything with it.  I'd argue that you don't really need the `return` statement.  If it were there, then you'd actually return the string `422`*, since again, it's all string concatenation at that level.

<sup>*:  This is from the last standing run if you printed it out after both were executed.  If it were printed out each time, you'd see `22` first.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`a+b+c` is `(a+b)+c`

The first addition adds the two numbers.

The second addition converts the result of the addition into a string, then concatenates it with the final string.

So ((2+1) + 3) = 6.0

and 6.0 + "3" = "6.0" + "3" = "6.03"